# AWS IAM: How to restrict PowerUser permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

suppose I have a role which has attached to AWS's managed policy PowerUserAccess:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:*",
                "organizations:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganization"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
     ]
}
```

It means it will allow everything but not "iam:*" and not "organizations:*" but it has some limit permission on iam and organization.

I want to attach an additional customized policy to limit cloudtrail permission of the role, so that only a few cloudtrail list/read access are allowed. then how should I implement this policy?
Should I create a second policy as follows?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
    "Effect": "Deny",
     "Action": [
      "cloudtrail:*",
      ],
      "Resource": [
         "*"
      ]
    },
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "cloudtrail:<a few read actions>",
      "cloudtrail:<a few list actioms>"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explicit deny trumps all other policies, so the above will deny all cloudtrail accesses.

You would have to deny just the policies you don't want users to have.

The AWS decision tree can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/images/AccessPolicyLanguage_Evaluation_Flow.diagram.png)

Comment: Thanks chris, what you mean is deny has highest priority, so in the second policy I just need to deny the things I want. will try,

Comment: Right.  As soon as you put in a deny, nothing else matters - the deny takes effect.  Since if nothing is specified, that is also assumed to be a deny, you need to allow just the calls you want to enable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a user with the `PowerUserAccess`, then you would need to give them **another policy** as you have shown above.

The `Deny` in the second policy will override the `Allow` from `PowerUserAccess`.

Alternatively, instead of using `PowerUserAccess`, you could create a new policy that gives them exactly the permissions you wish (effectively combining them both).

Comment: Thanks John, I have to keep them in PowerUser because this is not what I can determine :-)